# How to Fix “ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR” for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate

Do you use Google Chrome to browse the web? I have
 an SSL security error when browsing SSL secure websites on Google Chrome browser :

> This site can’t provide a secure connection – ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Thank you.